# Invalid hook call from calling a function from another .js file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file `file1` that looks like this:

```
import test from './file2.js'
function App(){
...
return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick = {test}>pressme</button>
  </div>
);
}
```

file 2 contains the function:

```
function test(){
  console.log("abc");
}

export default function irrelevant() {
  console.log("def");
  ...
}
```

Clicking the button that says "pressme" prints def to the console as well as two occurrences of the error: `react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call...`

What's happening here? I don't fully understand React and I'm trying to have a button wipe the page then run another .js file.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but just to make sure you are not getting confused... You are not importing `test` from file 2, you are importing `irrelevant` from file 2 and giving it the alias of `test` on import. If you wanted to export both functions you'd export like `export function test() ... export function irrelevant()...` then import like `import {test, irrelevant} from './file2.js`

Comment: The function looks fine. I think there's something else going on in your code, if you could share more of the error message, the app component and the irrelevant function we might be able to help further

Comment: @rook218 I see. Do I have to put the keyword `export` in order to be able to import it?

Comment: @pacifica94 Now that I understand the problem, I believe that the error messages were in the `irrelevant` function, in the ...

Comment: @ChristopherLee yes, the function/ variable will only be exposed if you `export` it from the source file